# jquery UI does not execute on new DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using the tabs from jquery UI inside a chrome extension. It works on existing DOM element, however, after inserting some new elements and running

```
$(function(){
        $( "div" ).tabs();
 });
```

again, the new elements does not the jquery tabs appearance.

my html file:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <h3 id = "tabId">Tab ID</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#0">Main Frame</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

html after running the script; taken from the console
    
      
      TabStructure

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="./jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="./jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-ui-1.10.3/demos/demos.css">
  <script src="background.js"></script>

  <script src="tabStructure.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-tabs-collapsible">
  <!-- this works -->
  <h3 id="tabId">Tab ID</h3>
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="0" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true"><a href="#0" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Main Frame</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="0" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-tabs-collapsible" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">

    <p>Process ID : 130</p>

    <ul> <!-- this part does not get processed by jquery ui-->
      <li><a href="#18">Sub_Frame: 18</a></li>
      <li><a href="#19">Sub_Frame: 19</a></li>
   </ul>

    <div id="18" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-tabs-collapsible">Frame ID : 18</div>
    <div id="19" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-tabs-collapsible">Frame ID : 19</div></div>
</div>



</body></html>
```

Comment: `$(function(){
        $("div").tabs();
 });` only executes 1 time *(on document.ready)*...you would need to execute `$("div").tabs();` after the insert of new divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the [`refresh()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-refresh) method after changing the DOM structure:

```
$( "div" ).tabs( "refresh" );
```

Note, this assumes you've initialized the plugin beforehand

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to execute the `refresh` method of the plugin to take into account the new DOM elements added after initialization:

```
$('div').tabs('refresh');
```

[Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-refresh)